# .desktop application error

Tags: .desktop

When I make the `Exec=/home/akif/Desktop/nwjs/nw`, the application starts up

But when I make the `Exec=./nw`, the application will show an error.

I am trying to run this application on more than one computer which is why I cannot have a personal directory `/home/akif/Desktop/nwjs/nw`. The directory 
could be downloaded anywhere in the computer. I would prefer if the other users not to have to run any code for permissions.

nw is the actual application which I need to run.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=app
Exec=/home/akif/Desktop/nwjs/nw
Icon=/home/akif/Desktop/nwjs/logo.png
Type=Application
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `Exec=$(where nw )`

Comment: Try `Exec=$HOME/Desktop/nwjs/nw` and if that works for you, let me know, and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: What if the appication isn't located in Desktop/

Comment: `$(where nw)` should take care of that. You can try `echo $(where nw)` and it shoudl tell you its path, as long as its in $PATH.

Comment: The question is, why do you expect the .desktop file to know where `./`is? @heynnema `$HOME` or any other relatives will never ever work like that from a .desktop file.

Comment: ^also @M.Becerra